# How to count number of pairs in a array? Need explanation for the given code

Tags: c++

Need explanation for the given code, I want to know what are the return types.  Here the `freq` map is returning what? And what's the need to increment `freq[p[i]]++`;

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long int
map<int,int> freq;
int CountPairs(int P[], int L, int R) {

  int count = 0;

  for (int i = L; i <R; ++i) {
    count += freq[P[i]];
    ++freq[P[i]];
  }
  return count;
}

int main()
{
    int n,a[2000];
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)cin>>a[i];
    cout<<CountPairs(a,0,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend using a debugger to single step through the code one line at a time.  *Watch* the variables as you execute each statement.

Comment: @rap The program counts duplicated numbers in the array. For example if the array has values { 5, 5, 2 } then the program outputs 1.

Comment: @rap  It is not clear why are you bothering about such a bad code instead of to learn good code examples.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Interesting hypothesis, but if the array has values {1,1,2,2,1,1} it outputs 7.

Comment: @molbdnilo I do not run the code. So I can make a mistake.:)

Answer (score 2):

`map[K]` will return the value corresponding to key K from the map.
If `map[K]` does not exist, it will call the default initializer for the value type and create a mapping. In this case, the type is `int`, so it will initialize the mapping to 0. On subsequent accesses, you will always get the current value of the mapping, which is incremented each time a value is found.

So for each duplicate, you're adding the number of occurrences of that value found in the array so far.

If you sum that up, the result will be:

[image: \sum_{i=L}^{R}\frac{N_i\cdot(N_i-1)}{2}]

where *L* is the left limit, *R* the right limit and *Ni* the number of occurrences of *i* in the array.

The code has multiple issues, though. You're reading `n` values into a statically sized array. If `n` is larger than 4000, you will overwrite the stack. Also, a global variable is used to keep the number of pairs for each value. If you call `CountPairs` multiple times, the numbers will increase. This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
map<int,int> freq;

count += freq[P[i]];

freq[P[i]] // create a pair within map with value 0 and key with `P[i]`
```

`++freq[P[i]]` increments the value with key as `P[i]` by 1.

So after first iteration value will be 1 and count will be zero.

So if there is pair, or triplet or quadruplet or etc, we will increment count+1.

By taking some insight from onitake, if there are 2 elements with same value, there will be one pair, if there are 3 elements with same value there will be 2 pairs.

**Key cnt value**

1     0     1

2     1     2

3     2    3

4     3

As said, if you are using it to count distinct pairs, it will fail, if there are same data repeats more than twice.

Comment: Actually, the result is correct. Consider that each value is a pair of each other duplicate value. So, if you have the same value twice, you will have one pair. If it occurs three times, you will have 2 pairs. If it occurs four times, you will have 6 pairs. The result is the sum of all `Ni·(Ni-1)/2`, where `Ni` is the number of occurrences of value `i`.

Comment: @onitake If you add that explanation to your answer, you might get some upvotes...

Comment: @onitake Thanks very much I corrected the answer